# railsでapplication.css以外のscssが反応しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

RailsでWebアプリケーションを作ろうとしています。application.cssの他にHomeコントローラを作成して、home.css.scssを作ってみたんですが、.classといった具合にセレクタ名を打ち込んでも全く反応しません。(文字色が白から変わらない、、)
application.cssはちゃんと読み込まれています。

ググってみるとよく出てくる、*/ = required_tree等も書いてあるはずなのに反応しません。なぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

1 拡張子をapplication.css.scssに変更
2 application.css内の記述をすべて消して

application.css.scssファイルの中で

@import "./home";

みたいな形で読み込んでみてください

Comment: 実行してみたんですが変わらず反応しません。他に方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: home.css.scssのファイルはどこに置かれていますか？？
application.css.scssと同じ階層ですか？？

Comment: application.css.scssと同じstylesheetsディレクトリ下にあります！